# how to wait for URL call to complete

Tags: android, url

I have this (attached)code which works perfectly on all the AVDs I create with eclipse. It calls a php file on a website. The php script files the xxx when the call http://somebody.me.uk/testingphp/signup.php?user=xxx is made. The php script does not give a response nor do I want one, the stuff in the loop of the code below is what I want to capture in the php file. In the real world, a nexus one phone with this code fails to contact the php script. In trying to resolve the problem I inserted lines of code creating toasts between the lines of code in the try block. Suddenly the app starts working and the php files the xxx. I presume this is due to introducing a delay on the nexus one while it shows the toasts, and gives chance for the communications to work. Any Ideas how to resolve the problem (without using toasts) Thank you.

```
private boolean hasSolution(){
        if (cells.solve()) {                
            // send to web site for QA analysis.
            String urlString = "http://somebody.me.uk/testingphp/signup.php?user=" ;
            for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
                for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
                    urlString += cells.getSolution(i, j);
                }// end for i
            }// end for j
    try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();                  
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                rd.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {Toast.makeText(app.this, "io error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            return true;
        }// end if
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//define this two variable in your activity

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog = null;  
private Runnable submittingScore;


submittingScore = new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() 
{
 try {
      do your task here
     } 

 catch (Exception e) {
pDialog.dismiss();
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

 };


 Thread thread =  new Thread(null, submittingScore, "MultibreifsBackground");
     thread.start();
pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(postServer.this,    
 "Please wait...", "Submitting Scores...", true);
```

Put the `pDialog.dismiss` in all the catch methods. Now when you call the URL, it will show processing until the URL is complete

Comment: Welcome but if this code is useful to you then please click on the above button of 0. which is at the left side of my answer.